# Calling an activity in module A or module B from module C

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have the following structure:

Module's `A`, `B` and `C`.

modules `A` and `B` are both two separate applications. They refer to some common code/functionality that is held within module `C`.

I have code in place that allows module `C` to differentiate between the current running "outer application" in order to call the correct activities.

However when I try to transfer from an activity in module `C` to either `A` or `B` by doing such:

```
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    //Add some values to the bundle...

    Intent returnToModuleA = new Intent();
    returnToModuleA .setComponent(new ComponentName(getBaseContext(),"SomeModuleAActivity"));

    returnToModuleA.putExtras(b);
    startActivity(returnToParentDashBoard);
```

I receive the error:

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.ModuleA/.activities.SomeModuleAActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

And I have defined the `SomeModuleAActivity` as such in my `AndroidManifest.xml` file for module `C`:

```
  <activity
    android:name=".SomeModuleAActivity"
    android:label="ModuleA">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.example.ModuleA.activities.SomeModuleAActivity"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

So I think that is clearly defined correctly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, SomeModuleAActivity.class));
```

Comment: Read the comments from the other answer and you'd see why I wasn't able to do this in the first place.

Comment: Nevermind, I guess the poster of the previous answer erased his.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try set **FULL NAME** instead of short name?

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.ModuleA.activities.SomeModuleAActivity"
    android:label="ModuleA">
</activity>
```

Try doing it like this, because due to different package name (since it is 2 different applications), the phone might not find the correct activity.